# Programming a Speedometer + Tachometer in Actionscript 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript

I need to create a Speedometer and a Tachometer in Actionscript 3.0 in Flash Professional.

I have searched around Stackoverflow and Googled for codes and examples but I have failed to find anything I can use. Most results point me to Android applications.

I also have close to zero experience in coding animations using AS.

What I need to do is to make the needles of the gauges move according to a certain formula. The formula does not need to be exact, it only needs to be logical.

When I hold down a key, the needles will move, when I let go, the needles will reverse to "0". The needles also cannot go over the limit.

Is this possible? I have tried putting codes together but they do not seem to be leading me the right way. I was also told that it is difficult.

Right now I am reading a book called Actionscript by Rob Huddleston, will this book help me?

Answer (score 0):

It is not difficult at all. Simplest way is to draw needle, move the center of the needle to the location where it is connected to gauge and then edit the rotation property of needle according to the return value of the function. Made you very quick sample to get you going: http://www.upload.ee/files/3141514/gauge.fla.html